# Keychain, rights to open it and save a copy

Tags: passwords, keychain

I begin to use Keychain for Mac OS Mavericks. If I understand the only way to secure the Keychain passwords is to put a password to open the computer, there is no password or security system to protect the Keychain.app. I mean if they have access to the computer they have access to mu Keychain passwords. Is that correct?

Now I have to send the computer to repair. Of course I have to give them access to the computer, that means that I have to save my passwords. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Why not just remove the hard drive before sending it for repair?  I was under the impression that most OEMs tell you to do this so they can't be held liable for missing data.

Comment: @Chris. It is an iMac, I do not know how to do that

Comment: There are videos online if you are technically inclined: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w6E2_XqaBw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Apple tech, I'd advise you not to take apart the mac especially if its under warranty. Check the warranty here: https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

The better option might be to create a standard account for them. They can get in and see if everything works but they will not be logging in to your information nor can they install anything without your permission. Apple menu > System Preferences > Users & Groups, create standard account.

Comment: I would also make sure the mac is not set to automatically log in as you. Same system preference, but click on Login and turn autologon off. Use a very cryptic password for your account.

Comment: this is a good option. I tried and it works. I see that by default there is an option "guest user". I suppose this could be used by the tech, and I do not need to create a special another account, is that correct?

Comment: Guest accounts should work also. Apple has a full description about all the different accounts here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14180

Comment: Because the are going to work on it, I always recommend backing up your data. We do not allow any data off campus so I create an image of the entire hard drive and replace it with a basic image. When the unit comes back, I reimage with the original and no data was lost or stolen. That is a whole other subject, though.